# How to write clause: WHERE num =... for a statement SELECT COUNT(*) as num...?

Tags: mysql

I have the statement

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as num_requests, ip_address FROM requests
GROUP BY ip_address
ORDER BY num_requests DESC;
```

When I use the following clause `WHERE num_requests = 3` I get a syntax error

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as num_requests, ip_address 
FROM requests
WHERE num_requests = 3
GROUP BY ip_address
ORDER BY num_requests DESC;
```

**Unknown column 'num_requests' in 'where clause'**

Is there any way I can use this `WHERE` clause without writing a nested query or join statement on the entire result set returned by the above?

Comment: I must say I find it odd to specifically sort by a value that you limit to be equal to 3.

Comment: It's just for sake of example, not a real-world application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `having` :)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as num_requests, ip_address FROM requests
GROUP BY ip_address
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
ORDER BY num_requests DESC;
```

To add a note on why `WHERE` couldn't be used but `HAVING` : with aggregates such as `SUM, MIN,MAX,AVG,COUNT` etc `WHERE` doen't work. So you have to use the latter.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as num_requests, ip_address 
FROM requests
GROUP BY ip_address
HAVING num_requests = 3
ORDER BY num_requests DESC
```

Comment: Juergen d ;) there's an EXTRA `WHERE` clause in your perfect answer.